# Getting error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when i am trying to access an object

Tags: php

Apologies for any misused terms but i am getting this error:

```
Notice
: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\Project\index.php
on line
63
```

When i run this code:

```
echo "<script> addResult({$i}, {$location}, {$link->data()->name}, {$link->data()->hash}, {$link->data()->upvotes}, {$link->data()->downvotes}) </script>";
```

This is the object(array?) i am pulling from:

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => Batman [hash] => QmZqkuqX1qTspb1GgmnzyRFetf1uMyA3CemvvgPZD39sPo [created] => 2020-06-17 03:33:02 [user_id] => [upvotes] => [downvotes] => )
```

I dont understand what seems to be

Small update, it seems that echoing it out works:

```
print_r($link->data()); //Above array/obj
echo $link->data()->name; //"Batman"
```

But assigning it to a variable/similar such as:

```
$name = $link->data()->name; //Throws above error
```

Does not work

Comment: It looks like you might be working with an object that has a getter and setter feature to it. You should see if there is a `toArray()` method where you can convert it to an array and access the attributes that way, so maybe something like `$link->data()->toArray()` or `$link->toArray()`. Sometimes, objects are  designed to use `get` as a method that actually returns the  value, so `$link->getName()` might return the `name` value. It's hard to say, just looking at what you have provided, but since `->data()` returns the `stdClass Object`, it sounds like it's using setter/getter.

Comment: I cant figure out how to convert it to an array so i guess that will be another question to ask haha. You are correct about the getter "data()" returns a private property _data. Any idea why this isint working tho? as `$link->data()->id` has worked in other parts of the App.

Comment: It's harder to say. You could probably convert it by using `$array = json_decode(json_encode($link->data()), 1);` That may convert it

Comment: Thank you very much this is a good workaround to the problem. Im kinda new to stack overflow so would this count as an answer to the problem or should i leave it open in case someone knows whats going on?

Comment: Yeah you can leave it open because what I gave you is a workaround for sure, but it would be helpful to know what the object is coming from unless this is some kind of custom framework, which it likely is. Some people are familiar with certain frameworks and such that may have experience in answering specifically what to do, but not knowing what that object is definitely hinders a proper answer. I would say, if it's custom and you are not familiar with it, you probably need to get back to the person who made it or you'll have to do some `debug_backtrace()` to figure out all it's moving parts.